# Cannot connect to port 3306 on a remote MySQL server using MySQL Workbench in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, networking, mysql, netstat

I want to access MySQL remotely:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO thufir@'192.168.0.16' IDENTIFIED BY 'hfdks4329vjkl';
```

When Workbench failed to connect, I took a look with ping and telnet:

```
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$ 
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$ ping 192.168.0.21
PING 192.168.0.21 (192.168.0.21): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.21: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.274 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.21: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.499 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.21 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.274/0.387/0.499/0.113 ms
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$ 
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$ telnet 192.168.0.21
Trying 192.168.0.21...
^C
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$ 
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$ telnet 192.168.0.21 3306
Trying 192.168.0.21...
^C
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$
```

I'm installing `coreutils` and will have to learn how to use `netstat` on the Mac, and `lsof` -- apparently it's different.

The `arrakis` server is running `OpenSuSE`; it has closed ports?

Note:  I haven't installed MySQL on the Mac, it [gives me errors](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177528/to-use-mysql-system-preferences-must-quit-and-reopen-and-quit-and-reopen)...

------------------------------------------------------------------------------update

```
MariaDB [mysql]> 
MariaDB [mysql]> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO `thufir`@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> 
MariaDB [mysql]> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> 
MariaDB [mysql]> select host, user, grant_priv from user;
+------------+--------+------------+
| host       | user   | grant_priv |
+------------+--------+------------+
| localhost  | root   | Y          |
| linux-k7qk | root   | Y          |
| 127.0.0.1  | root   | Y          |
| ::1        | root   | Y          |
| localhost  |        | N          |
| linux-k7qk |        | N          |
| %          | cron   | N          |
| localhost  | cron   | N          |
| localhost  | custom | N          |
| %          | custom | N          |
| %          | slave  | N          |
| %          | root   | N          |
| %          | thufir | N          |
+------------+--------+------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]>
```

Comment: If ping works but a telnet times out, then the port is firewalled somewhere; probably incoming on `arrakis` although it could be possible that outpoing ports on the mac are blocked (but not probable). Note also that often mysql is bound to `127.0.0.1` to prevent attacks, so you'll need to modify the mysql server config (`bind-address`).

Answer (score 2):

To enable networking in MySQL you need to make sure two things are handled correctly: MySQL grants and MySQL itself needs to have networking enabled:

#### Setting MySQL grants.

Your `GRANT` command seems odd to me:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO thufir@'192.168.0.16' IDENTIFIED BY 'hfdks4329vjkl';
```

Why is the `'192.168.0.16'` in single quotes but the user is not? It might see that `'192.168.0.16'` as literal with the single quotes for the host. So try doing it like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'thufir@192.168.0.16' IDENTIFIED BY 'hfdks4329vjkl';
```

But when I grant permissions like this, there are *two* commands and they are structured like this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'thufir@192.168.0.16' IDENTIFIED BY 'thufir';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'thufir@192.168.0.16';
```

And then after setting grants you must flush the privileges table to get the new privileges to load in:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And you should be good to go.

#### Enable MySQL networking.

But that said, check your `my.cnf` and if there is a `bind-address` setting like this:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

That would bind MySQL to `localhost` (ie: `127.0.0.1`) by default and is normal “out of box” security behavior for MySQL since exposing database servers to a network can be a security risk. So in this case—since you need networking enabled—you need to comment it out like this:

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

And also make sure `skip-networking` is disabled, commented out like this:

```
#skip-networking
```

And then restart the MySQL server for the new settings to take effect.

#### Postscript.

Now all that said, the MySQL `GRANT` command you have uses the IP address `192.168.0.16` but all of your `ping` and `telnet` tests are for `192.168.0.21`. So which IP address is it? When you set grants in MySQL, you do so based on the *client* IP address; not the server IP address.

So if the server has the IP address `192.168.0.16` and the client has the IP address `192.168.0.21`, then the MySQL `GRANT` command should use `192.168.0.21` and *not* the `192.168.0.16` as your examples show. Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: I'll have to try the postscript tomorrow.

Comment: Your comment about skip-networking solved my problem, it is not mentioned in other sites and answers. Thx